# Absolution without confession is valid or not?

Tags: confession, oriental-orthodox

Being a Syrian Orthodox, I have a doubt...
Will my sind be forgiven if I get HUSOYO/(***absolution prayer only with no confession***) instead of confession of sins?
I usually confess once in a month but the weeks in between, if I get HUSOYO will it forgive my sins?

Comment: I would suggest we go back to the Bible for a fundamental question such as this: First Jesus taught us to pray: Abba Father....forgive our trespasses as we ..; and 1 John 1:9 - If we confess our sins, He  is faithful and just to forgive us our sins and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness." ; "Therefore, brothers, since we have confidence to enter the holy places by the blood of Jesus-Heb. 10:19.  Traditions, rituals, word of absolution  will not have any bearing. They will not be there when you stand there! If you in faith go by the Scripture, the Word will be there. God bless.